# Jinja Function Call within DBT model

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

Just wondering, does jinja not apply a function to every row in a dbt sql/model table?

```
With my_cte AS (
  Select 
    t.id as id, 
    {{my_func('id')}} as amount
  From table t
)
```

It returns the same value for column 'amount' in every row in the CTE. It seems to calculate the value for the first row and use it for every row. Is this normal? I am assuming it would returns same results as an sql applied function with different values for each row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This is normal**

The way of dbt works split to two steps.

1. compiled the model into normal SQL statement. The compiled sql are located in `target/compiled` folder. We can copy the compiled sql and run directly in data warehouse environment. It is very useful for debugging purpose.
2. send the compiled sql to provided data warehouse target in `profiles.yml` file.

At the time sql compiled, it is fixed. While the fixed part can be a sql function. That sql function then will be evaluated by data warehouse row by row. The sql function can be built-in function by data warehouse or custom one usually by running `CREATE FUNCTION`. here is an example of for postgres.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION add_numbers(a integer, b integer)
RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN a + b;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```